# Node.JS how to capture field value and send to server side using Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, kendo-grid

I have a Node.JS express app using Jade as my front end. I know how to pass variable from the backend to the front end, but how do I pass data back to server side. For example I have a grid that is populated from a database. When I add a new row in the front end, I need to pass it to the backend so that it can log it into the database.

Comment: You probably want to use AJAX, but I think you're confusing terms here; you're not passing variables to the front-end, Jade is still in the back-end as a templating system. Once the markup is rendered it's static.

Comment: i thought about that. So I would make local POST/PUT/GET request to backend and then backend would send to database? The database is on a different server so I have access to cross domain rules.

Comment: i see. you are correct.so once its static communication stops.

Comment: Yes, basically. Typically you'd first create your site with a  page refresh pattern (GET/POST) with query vars in url; then add AJAX as enhancement.

Comment: ok. man, it seems like node and express would have come up with something nifty

Comment: Well, Express is very barebones framework. Browse `npm`, there are many AJAX libraries out there. AJAX front-end stuff...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass data object from jade to node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201644/how-to-pass-data-object-from-jade-to-node-js)